# Roblox Pathfinding Back and forth movement when reaching the destination requires jumping

Tags: roblox

For some reason when the destination target is placed somewhere where it requires jumping to get to my NPC is moving towards it while keep switching between moving back and forth.

Code:

```
local path = PathfindingService:CreatePath()

local waypoints
local currentWaypointIndex

local function followPath(destinationObject)
    
    path:ComputeAsync(enemyNPC.HumanoidRootPart.Position, destinationObject.Position)

    waypoints = {}

    if path.Status == Enum.PathStatus.Success then
        waypoints = path:GetWaypoints()
        currentWaypointIndex = 1
        humanoid:MoveTo(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].Position)
    else
        error("Path not really working")
    end
end

local function onWaypointReached(reached)
    if reached and currentWaypointIndex < #waypoints then
        currentWaypointIndex += 1

        if waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].Action == Enum.PathWaypointAction.Jump then
            humanoid:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)
        end

        humanoid:MoveTo(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].Position)
    end

    if reached and currentWaypointIndex >= #waypoints then
        print("Target reached!")
        animationTrack:Stop()
    end
end

local function onPathBlocked(blockWaypointIndex)
    if blockWaypointIndex > currentWaypointIndex then
        followPath(destination)
    end
end

path.Blocked:Connect(onPathBlocked)

humanoid.MoveToFinished:Connect(onWaypointReached)
followPath(destination)
```

(I delted the top part of the code with some local variables because it didn't let me post the whole thing without saying my post is mostly code)

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the action in the [PathWaypoint](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/PathWaypoint), which is an [PathWaypointAction](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/PathWaypointAction) Enum. You have to determine whether the PathWaypoint is a Walk or Jump action. Currently, you're doing `MoveTo()` regardless of whether it has to jump or not.

So, in your code:

```lua
if waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].Action == Enum.PathWaypointAction.Jump then
     humanoid:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)
else
     ​humanoid:MoveTo(waypoints[currentWaypointIndex].Position)
end
```